# javascript's _.where in python

Tags: python, dictionary

At http://underscorejs.org/, there is an underscorejs utility `where`,

```
_.where(listOfPlays, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}
```

which returns,

```
[{title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
 {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}]
```

How can i do this in python without using a `for in` iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would like to use list comprehensions. However it does involve `for` and `in`:

```
>>> listOfPlays = [{'title': x, 'author': x, 'year': 1611} for x in ('Shakespeare', 'someone')]
>>> listOfPlays
[{'author': 'Shakespeare', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'Shakespeare'}, {'author': 'someone', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'someone'}]
>>> 
>>> [x for x in listOfPlays if x['author'] == 'Shakespeare' and x['year'] == 1611]
[{'author': 'Shakespeare', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'Shakespeare'}]
```

Alternatively, you could use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x['author'] == 'Shakespeare' and x['year'] == 1611, listOfPlays)
[{'author': 'Shakespeare', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'Shakespeare'}]
```

**EDITED:** Please notice that above examples are evaluated in Python 2. In Python 3 the built-in function [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) returns an iterable instead of a list.

Comment: @kAlmAcetA ..do you mean that things like hardcoded conditions are not allowed in SO answers as brief & clear examples?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]`

```
def filter_by_dict(list_of_dicts, conditions):
    def _check(item):
        # returns True only if first is subset of second
        # in python3 you should use items()
        return conditions.viewitems() <= item.viewitems()

    return filter(_check, list_of_dicts)

TEST = [
    {"title": "Cymbeline", "author": "Shakespeare", "year": 1611},
    {"title": "Otherr", "author": "Shakespeare", "year": 1612},
    {"title": "The Tempest", "author": "Shakespeare", "year": 1611}
]
print(filter_by_dict(TEST, {"author": "Shakespeare", "year": 1611}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to `_.where` can be written in python in 1 line as a list comprehension, but it will use `for ... in` syntax :

```
def where(elems, **kwargs):
    """where(iterable, **filter_conditions) --> filtered iterable"""
    return [el for el in elems if all(el.get(k) == v for k, v in kwargs.items())]
```

Alternatively, use `filter` & `map`to avoid using `for ... in`:

```
def where(elems, **kwargs):
    """where(iterable, **filter_conditions) --> filter object"""
    def picker(elem): 
        return all(map(lambda x: elem.get(x[0]) == x[1], kwargs.items()))
    return filter(picker, elems)
```

On python 2, both versions of the `where` function are called as:

```
where(listOfPlays, author='Shakespeare', year=1611)
```

On python 3, the latter version needs to be wrapped in a list, because `filter` returns a filter object instead, i.e

```
list(where(listOfPlays, author='Shakespeare', year=1611))
```